# Pythagorean triples generation Euclid's proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show that $a,\,b,\,c$ have no common divisor where $a = s\cdot t,\,b = \frac{(s^2 -t^2)}{2},\,c = \frac{(s^2 + t^2)}{2}$ and $s,\,t$ are both odd and they are relatively prime? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Consider $gcd(b+c,b-c)$...

Comment: that equals to 1 since s and t are relatively prime. Is that also mean gcd(b,c) = 1?

Comment: Let $p$ be prime. If $p$ divides $b$ and $c$, then $p$ divides their sum and difference $s^2$ and $t^2$, so $p$ divides $s$ and $t$, contradicting the fact that $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can see it

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what holds when a number divides $a$? What does it say about the divisibility of $s + t$?

Comment: If a number divides a, it can divide s or t or both of them. If it cannot divide both of them s + t is not divisible by that.

Comment: And if the number is prime? Can you apply the same logic for $s + t$ to the expressions for $b$ and $c$?